# mdframed nested frametitle bug

Tags: mdframed

> **This issue is fixed in version 1.6b**
>   [`mdframed at github`](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed)

When nesting frames the inner most frametitle is used. The frametitle for all these is frame3.

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={frame1}]
asdf
    \begin{mdframed}[frametitle={frame2}]
    134
        \begin{mdframed}[ frametitle={frame3}]
            asdf1324
        \end{mdframed}
    \end{mdframed}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

(mdframed v1.4)

Comment: First time I see such a using. ;-). Note that this can't be splitted well.

Comment: Not sure what you mean that it can't be splitted well? Everything seems to work but the title(may not be perfect but works for what I'm trying to do). I suppose basically whatever function is not "reentrant" in that it uses a "global variable" for the frame title. What happens is the inner frame ends up overwriting the outer frame which is displayed after(for some reason, possibly to get the size right) the content of the frame. Should be an easy fix by just putting the title in a "local variable".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT: I uploaded a new test version to github. Please check it out.

https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed

[image]

---

With the current version you can't change this behavior. To assign the frame title I am using a group and the contents is saved in a box. To get a global access to the box I need the command `\global`. So in your case I overwrite the last frame title.

I will think about this request and maybe I will change the implementation.

<sub>This is the best answer I can provide so far</sub>

Comment: In some other questions I had several answers that used a global stack. Maybe you can use the interpretations it as a quick and easy solution? (simply push the title on the "stack" on each nesting then pop them when ready to use)

Comment: @Uiy: Do you have a link?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51070/push-pop-or-save-a-length-dimension My guess is, any time you use the title text, just convert to using the stack... need to push it at the start of the environment and then pop it and use it right when it is displayed... this should reduce all issues unless you have to deal with measuring issues in which case you might try poping it and using it right before the geometrical calculations.

Comment: @Uiy: I remember this question. I will think about this tomorrow.

Comment: @Uiy: Please see my update.

Comment: I don't know if I can compile it or not as I use miktex and the auto update feature but if you say it works then it works ;)

Comment: @Uiy: In the example. You can download everything from github and than run the bat-file.

Answer (score 3):

I also had problems with nested boxes using `mdframed` inside a `beamerposter` document (nested boxes are quite common on posters). I decided to give `tcolorbox` a try, and it has no problems with arbitrarily nested boxes (this is example is stolen from the CTAN package example file):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\section{Boxes in boxes}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=yellow!50!black,
  every box/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries},title=Box]
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=red!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,
    colbacktitle=red!85!black,
    title=Box inside box,drop fuzzy shadow]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[beamer,colframe=blue!50!black,title=Box inside box inside box]
      An now for something completely different: Boxes!\par\medskip
      \newtcbox{\mybox}{nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,colframe=green!50!black,colback=green!10!white,arc=0pt}
      \mybox{This} \mybox{is} \mybox{another} \mybox{box.}
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image: Nested boxes using tcolorbox]

Have a look at the beautiful [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) with lots of examples. Especially noteworthy are the available skins, e.g. the "enhanced" skin which uses `TikZ` internally. With this, you can create box designs you would not have thought are possible in Latex, have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64118/36602).

So while this might not solve your problem, it provides a good alternative for typesetting nested framed boxes in Latex.