# Passing stack data to tikz node names

Tags: tikz-pgf, stack

I'm trying to use a stack data structure (as discussed here: [Push/Pop or save a length/dimension?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51070/push-pop-or-save-a-length-dimension)) to store the various names of a set of tikzmark node names (as discussed in [`tikzmark` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzmark/tikzmark.pdf)) scatted throughout my text.

Separately the stack implementation (WE1) and `\tikzmark` (WE2) work perfectly, but their combined behaviours somehow clash with multiples errors.

I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong when I try passing the popped stack data elements as node names within a `\tikzmark` command (MWE below). Is this a problem arising from my LaTeX code not immediately evaluating the \pop commands (I've tried playing around with `\expandafter` and `\edef` to no success...)?  I've also tried passing `\pop{\latexstack}` to a `\newcommand{}`, but I haven't managed to get that method to work either...

**MWE** [Incorrect combined behaviours...]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext, tikz}
    \newtoks\latexstack
    \latexstack={\empty}

    \def\push#1#2{
        \begingroup
        \toks0={{#1}}
        \edef\act{\endgroup\global#2={\the\toks0 \the#2}}\act
    }

    \def\pop#1{
        \begingroup
        \edef\act{\endgroup\noexpand\SplitOff\the#1(tail)#1}\act
    }

    \def\SplitOff#1#2(tail)#3{
        \ifx#1\empty
            \errhelp{Attempting to pop empty stack #3.}
            \errmessage{You can't pop an empty stack.}
        \else
            #1\global#3={#2}
        \fi
    }

    \newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node(#1) {};}

\begin{document}
    \push{A1}{\latexstack}
    \push{B2}{\latexstack}

    \blindtext \tikzmark{\pop{\latexstack}}\\ 
    \blindtext \tikzmark{\pop{\latexstack}}\\ 

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,scale=0.5] 
        \draw[red] (A) -- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**WE1** [Correct behaviour of stack data structure: A1, B2, C3, and D4 are pushed and sequentially popped from the data structure]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \newtoks\latexstack
    \latexstack={\empty}

    \def\push#1#2{
        \begingroup
        \toks0={{#1}}
        \edef\act{\endgroup\global#2={\the\toks0 \the#2}}\act
    }

    \def\pop#1{
        \begingroup
        \edef\act{\endgroup\noexpand\SplitOff\the#1(tail)#1}\act
    }

    \def\SplitOff#1#2(tail)#3{
        \ifx#1\empty
            \errhelp{Attempting to pop empty stack #3.}
            \errmessage{You can't pop an empty stack.}
        \else
            #1\global#3={#2}
        \fi
    }

\begin{document}
    \push{A1}{\latexstack}
    \push{B2}{\latexstack}
    \push{C3}{\latexstack}
    \push{D4}{\latexstack}

    \pop{\latexstack},\\ 
    \pop{\latexstack},\\ 
    \pop{\latexstack},\\ 
    \pop{\latexstack}.
\end{document}
```

**WE2** [Correct behaviour of `\tikzmark`: Points A and B are marked, and connected together with a red line]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext, tikz}

    \newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node(#1) {};}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext \tikzmark{A}\\
    \blindtext \tikzmark{B}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,scale=0.5] 
        \draw[red] (A) -- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem here is expansion. When TikZ creates nodes the node name is fully expanded using `\edef`.

Assuming the OPs original code then consider the following

```
\push{A1}{\latexstack}
\push{B2}{\latexstack}
\edef\nodename{\pop{\latexstack}}
\show\nodename
```

This illustrates the full expansion and will give (in the log file):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pop #1^^@- \begingroup \edef \act 
                                 {\endgroup \noexpand \SplitOff \the #1(tail...
l.36     \edef\nodename{\pop{\latexstack}
                                       }
! Undefined control sequence.
\pop ... \noexpand \SplitOff \the #1(tail)#1}\act 

l.36     \edef\nodename{\pop{\latexstack}
                                       }
> \nodename=macro:
-> \begingroup \edef {\endgroup \SplitOff {B2}{A1}\empty (tail)\latexstack }.
l.37     \show\nodename
```

Note the problem is *not* that `\act` is undefined. The errors will disappear if `\let\act=\relax` is placed somewhere in the preamble, but the contents of `\nodename` is still a whole bunch of LaTeX code, not the desired node name.

One solution is to have a `\popto` command which pops the value at the top of the stack into a macro which is then used as a node name (NB. I also reimplemented the `\push` macro):

```
\def\push#1#2{%
  \def\tmp{{#1}}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
    #2\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\tmp\the#2}%
\ignorespaces}

\def\popto#1#2{%
  \expandafter\SplitOffTo\the#1\stop{#1}{#2}%  
}

\def\SplitOffTo#1#2\stop#3#4{%
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\tmp\empty%
    \errhelp{Attempting to pop empty stack #3.}%
    \errmessage{You can't pop an empty stack.}%
  \else%
    \def#4{#1}\global#3={#2}%
  \fi%
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
\newtoks\latexstack
\latexstack={\empty}
\push{A1}{\latexstack}
\push{B2}{\latexstack}

\popto{\latexstack}{\nodename}
\tikzmark{\nodename}
\show\nodename
Some text \tikzmark{\nodename}

\popto{\latexstack}{\nodename}
\tikzmark{\nodename}
\show\nodename
Some more text \tikzmark{\nodename}
```

The log file will show (something like) this:

```
> \nodename=macro:
->B2.
l.31 \show\nodename

> \nodename=macro:
->A1.
l.34 \show\nodename
```

If all of that seems like a bit of a nuisance then the `\popto` stuff could be tied up in a `\tikzmarkpop` macro:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\push#1#2{%
  \def\tmp{{#1}}% 
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
    #2\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\tmp\the#2}%
\ignorespaces}

\def\popto#1#2{%
  \expandafter\SplitOffTo\the#1\stop{#1}{#2}%  
}

\def\SplitOffTo#1#2\stop#3#4{% 
  \def\tmp{#1}
  \ifx\tmp\empty% 
    \errhelp{Attempting to pop empty stack #3.}%
    \errmessage{You can't pop an empty stack.}%
  \else%
    \def#4{#1}\global#3={#2}%
  \fi}


\def\tikzmarkpop#1{%
\popto{#1}{\nodename}%
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\coordinate(\nodename);} 

\newtoks\latexstack
\latexstack={\empty}

\begin{document}

\push{A1}{\latexstack}
\push{B2}{\latexstack}  

Some text\tikzmarkpop{\latexstack}
Some more text\tikzmarkpop{\latexstack}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
  \draw [red, <->] (A1) -- (B2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Thanks Mark; problem well and truly solved!