# How to have nested mdframes with different frame titles

Tags: mdframed, nesting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [mdframed nested frametitle bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48534/mdframed-nested-frametitle-bug)

> **This issue is fixed in version 1.6b**
> [`mdframed at github`](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed)

It seems as if the frame title used in the `mdframed` environment can only have one value, which is problematic if the mdframes are nested.

For example, if I specify the title of an mdframe to as `frametitle={Outer Title}`, and then nest another mdframe within this with `frametitle={Inner Title}`, the output I get is:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.0cm]{geometry}% makes output image more palatable for TeX.SE
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Outer Title}]
    \begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Inner Title}]
    \end{mdframed}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you can check that for explanation and work around :
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48534/mdframed-nested-frametitle-bug

Comment: @LaRaison: Thanks. I guess then this is a duplicate of that...

Comment: @PeterGrill: I didn't upload the new version because TL is frozen.