# pgfkeys error in tcolorbox

Tags: pgfkeys, tcolorbox

I am trying to duplicate part of an example code given in the `tcolorbox` package documentation on page 13. It looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbset{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,nobeforeafter,width=(\linewidth-4mm)/2}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,title=Lower not separated,lower separated=false]
This is the upper part.
\tcblower
This is the lower part.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It all looks good except for the dashed vertical line that should not be there. The above code generates the error:

```
pgfkeys:Ido not know the key /tcb/lower separated...
```

The log file sends me to the `pgfkeys` package. Section 55 on Key Management (page 481) in the pgfmanual doesn't provide me with an answer.So what's wrong here? Perhaps there's just something missing as in this example: [Problem with "Package pgfkeys Error"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64117/problem-with-package-pgfkeys-error).

And how to give each part a different color?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Running your example I don't get any errors: do you have the last version? Mine is 2.51 (2013/09/16).

Comment: I just compiled your example without error messages. My guess is that you work with an old version of `tcolorbox`. The current version is 2.51 (2013/09/16). The specific key was introduced with version 2.33. You should check your logfile for your version, i.e. a line like `Package: tcolorbox 2013/09/16 version 2.51 text color boxes` for the current version.